# Finitely generated A-module, localization and canonical homomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

> (a) Let $A$ be  a commutative ring and $S\subseteq A$ be a multiplicatively closed set. If $S^{-1} A$ is a finite A-module, then $S^{-1} A$ is isomorphic to the A-module $A/\ker i_S$, where $i : A \to S^{-1} A$ is the natural ring homomorphism.

Attempt: I think, by theorem of natural homomorphism on modules, $S^{-1} A $ should always be isomorphic to the $A$-module $A/ \ker i_S$, why is finiteness of $S^{-1}A$ necessary?

> (b) Let $A$ be an integral domain , $S_0 = A\setminus\{0\}$ and $K= {S_0}^{-1} A=Q(A)$ be the quotient field of $A$. Then prove that  $A=K$ if and only if the canonical homomorphism
> ${S_0}^{-1} \operatorname{Hom}_A(K,A) \to \operatorname{Hom}_{{S_0}^{-1}A } ({S_0}^{-1} K, {S_0}^{-1} A)$ is surjective.

I am really sorry but for (b), I am not able to make any progress for any side, despite thinking a lot.

Kindly guide!

Comment: $S^{-1}A$ is isomorphic to $A/\ker i_S$ if and only if $i_S:A \to S^{-1}A$ is surjective.

Comment: The finiteness hypothesis is absolutely necessary (for part a). Indeed, localization will generally give you algebras that are not even finitely generated (as algebras).

Comment: @yearning4pi Why finiteness hypothesis is absolutely necessary?

Comment: Here's a more trivial explanation than what I intended (initially): Part a is saying that if $S^{-1}A$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, then it is in fact generated by just one element ($i(1_A)$). If it is not finitely generated as an $A$-module, then it cannot by generated by just one element. OK, now here is what I was thinking about when I gave the original comment. It is much more typical to have $A$ embed $S^{-1}A$ properly,. For instance, this happens you localize an integral domain (any $S$) or localize a ring $R$ with respect to $S=\{1,f,f^2,\dots\}$ for a non-zero divisor $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) As mentioned in the comments, if $i_S\colon A\to S^{-1}A$ is surjective, we have the desired isomorphism $A/\ker(i_S)\cong S^{-1}A$.

Let $a_1/s_1,\dots,a_n/s_n\in S^{-1}A$ be a set of generators for the $A$-module $S^{-1}A$. By multiplying appropriate elements of $S$ to the denominators, we may assume $s=s_1=\dots=s_n$. [*This is where we use finiteness*] Now if $b/t\in S^{-1}A$ is an arbitrary element, then $$b/(st)=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\cdot a_i/s$$for some $b_i\in A$.
Now multiplying $s\in S$ shows
$$b/t=\sum_{i=1}^nb_i\cdot a_i/1=i_S\big(\sum_{i=1}^nb_ia_i\big),$$
so $i_S$ is surjective.

(b) *Outline:* One direction is obvious. Suppose $S_0^{-1}\hom_A(K,A)\to \hom_K(K,K)$ is surjective. In particular, since $\hom_K(K,K)\cong K\ne0$, there must be a nonzero $A$-homomorphism $f\colon K\to A$. This should show that $A=K$.

Comment: @Jimmy Can you please tell how finiteness was used in the step where you mentioned: This is where we use finiteness?

Comment: how did you wrote that $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i a_i /1 = i_S ( \sum_{i=1}^n b_i a_i )$ and how this implies $i_S$ is surjective? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: To the first question: when $n=2$, we have $a_1/s_1=a_1s_2/s_1s_2,a_2/s_2=a_2s_1/s_1s_2$, so letting $s_1s_2=s'$, $a_1s_2=a_1'$, and $a_2s_1=a_2'$, the elements $a_1'/s'$ and $a_2'/s'$, which was what we wanted. The same method generalizes, letting $s'=s_1\dots s_n$, and $a_i'=a_i\cdot s_1\dots s_{i-1}\cdot s_{i+1}\dots s_n$. Finiteness was used here, since you cannot normalize the denominators for infinitely many elements (e.g., consider $1,1/2,1/3,\dots\in\mathbb Q=(\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\})^{-1}\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: To the second question: this is how $i_S$ is defined; for any element $x\in A$, you have $i_S(x)=x/1\in S^{-1}A$. Since $b/t=i_S(\dots)$ and $b/t$ was an arbitrary element of $S^{-1}A$, this proves $i_S$ is surjective.

Comment: Kindly tell how 1 direction is obvious.

Comment: In (b) you made a typo in $S_0^{-1}\hom_A(K,A)\to \hom_K(K,K)$ ,on right of -> it should be $hom_{K}( {S_0}^{-1} K, K)$

Comment: So, I think you need to edit proof of (b).

Comment: @Jimmy note that $S_0^{-1}K=K$.

Comment: I have asked many questions in commutative algebra  a lot of which are unanswered. Can you please help me with some of those. I am from the poorest part of this planet and this site is my only help!